# Select similar vertex in a symmetric mesh

Tags: selection-tools

I'm looking for a way to speed up my work in blender, i have a mesh, decagon polygon. I want to select all the vertex similar like in the picture below. Is there a quick way to do this ? without doing everytime with mouse. I found the SHIFT+G option but it didn't resolve my problem. Thank you[image]

Comment: What do you mean similar to the vertex? Do you mean you want to select that whole loop quickly?

Comment: Not the entire loop cut, but just a couple of vertex for every edge of the loop cut as i did in the picture above.What i mean if is there a way to select all of the vertex  of a mesh with a certain pattern, if this pattern is repeated more time in the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to select everything in that loop but vertices in the middle is to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *By Length* in Edge selection mode. Select one long edge from the loop and run *[Select Similar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-similar)* command.

[image]

Then convert that selection to the pattern shown on your screenshot by changing Selection mode to *Vertex*.
However this way may not be the best since it will select all the edges falling under the specified length threshold (length of the active edge).

Another way is to use *[Checker Deselect](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#checker-deselect)* to deselect vertices you don't need to be selected according to certain pattern.

First select the edge loop with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> on it. Then deselect and select again vertex in between long edges to make it active. Run *Checker Deselect* from *Select* menu in the viewport footer or from the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> menu. Change its settings to *Nth Selection* - 2 (to deselect every 2nd element), *Skip* - 2 (to skip every 2 steps of selection) and *Offset* - to 2 (to offset the start of selection).

[image: checker-deselect-GIF]

Comment: Checker Deselect is so powerfull. I didn't know that. Thank you